# Why default value for property descriptor configurable in javascript is false when declaring a variable with 'var'?

Tags: javascript

Why attribute 'configurable' is by default 'false' when declared a variable using 'var' and if variable declared in global scope without 'var' its configurable 'true'?

```
   // variable declared in global scope with 'var' keyword

          var foo = 2;
          Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, 'foo')

   // will print {value: 2, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: false}


   // But with variable declared without var has configurable true

          bar = 2;   

   // will print {value: 2, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true}
```

Comment: Are you asking for an explanation of the decision behind this difference or an explanation of the spec (i.e. where this is defined in the spec)?

Comment: asking for an explanation of the decision behind this difference